# What is the best possible way to write each element of an array to a new line of a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example this code writes the entire array to a single line:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('myfile.txt', mydataarray, 'utf-8');
```

Where as this code needs a loop and multiple call to **fs** API.

```
for(var i = 0; i < mydataarray.length; i++){
  fs.appendFile('myfile.txt', mydataarray[i]+"\n", (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
```

Is there a way to do this at once like the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
fs.writeFileSync('myfile.txt', mydataarray.join('\n'), 'utf-8');
```